# Why does futures::lock::Mutex not implement RefUnwindSafe

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

`futures::lock::Mutex` is not implementing `RefUnwindSafe` trait (see https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/lock/struct.Mutex.html#impl-RefUnwindSafe )

Why is not safe to pass a `futures::lock::Mutex` inside `std::panic::catch_unwind`?

Reproducible code:

```rust
use std::panic::catch_unwind;
use futures::lock::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let m = Mutex::new(String::new());
    
    catch_unwind(|| {
      m.lock()
    });
}
```

Could `futures::lock::Mutex` implement the `RefUnwindSafe` trait ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `UnwindSafe` trait hints at a reason for this:

> ## Who implements UnwindSafe?
>
> Types such as &mut T and &RefCell are examples which are not unwind safe. The general idea is that any mutable state which can be shared across catch_unwind is not unwind safe by default. This is because it is very easy to witness a broken invariant outside of catch_unwind as the data is simply accessed as usual.
>
> Types like &Mutex, however, are unwind safe because they implement poisoning by default. They still allow witnessing a broken invariant, but they already provide their own “speed bumps” to do so.

`futures::lock::Mutex` provides mutability like `&mut T` and `RefCell<T>`, but does not implement the poisoning feature of `std::sync::Mutex<T>`, so it does not implement `UnwindSafe`.

Though as the documentation points out, the `UnwindSafe` is less about memory safety and more about upholding logical invariants - hence why neither `UnwindSafe` nor `AssertUnwindSafe` are `unsafe`.